# One resultset for many tables DBIx::class

Tags: sql, catalyst, dbix-class

I have a database with many tables that are structured the same and have the same column names.

```
Table 1
col1 
col2
col3

Table 2
col1
col2
col3
```

and so on.

I'm trying to learn how to use DBIx::Class and Catalyst with this type of setup.

Normally I have a subroutine like:

```
sub query{
my($table) = @_;
$sql = "SELECT col1 FROM $table;";
$qh=$connect->prepare($sql) or die print $DBI::errstr;
$qh->execute() or die print $DBI::errstr;
}
```

... getting the results and so forth

I can think of how to do it from the controller.

```
my $table = "DB::Table1";
my $result = $c->model($table)->create({col1 => $col1, col2=>$col2});
```

That's fine. But what about writing the the Results and ResultSets? I don't want to have to write many, in one instance tens of ResultSets that are essentially the same thing just on a different table.

Is there any way to write a ResultSet that takes as a parameter a table and queries based on that? I tried to write a 'Global' ResultSet, but got an error that there were no Results with that name.

Is it possible to use DBIx::Class with this kind of setup?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write a Moose role which you apply to each ResultSet class.

Comment: Thanks. I spent some time reading up on Moose roles, and found this article [link](http://www.catalystframework.org/calendar/2010/22). I thinks thats getting me in the right direction.